# Tkinter: How to access a label to configure?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make it so that the user can open a prompt, and then return that on the tkinter app. However, every time I do this, I get the error AttributeError: 'ImportPage' object has no attribute 'textLabel'

```
class ImportPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        ttk.Label(self, text="This is the Import Configuration Page", font = LARGE_FONT).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Import Files", command = self.import_File).pack()
        textLabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Test File:" , font=NORM_FONT)
        textLabel.pack()
        ttk.Button(self, text="Return to start page",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage)).pack()

    def import_File(self):
        global posTime_file_path
        posTime_file_path = fd.askopenfilename()
        self.textLabel.config(text="Test File:" + posTime_file_path)
```

Edit: I figured it out. The reason is because when I initialized textLabel I did not call self. This is a classic noob mistake. I'll leave this post up in case it helps anyone.

Correct code should be:

```
self.textLabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Test File:" , font=NORM_FONT)
self.textLabel.pack()
```

Comment: Please leave the solution as answer and accept it.

Comment: will do. thx......

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The reason is because when I initialized textLabel I did not call self. This is a classic noob mistake. I'll leave this post up in case it helps anyone.

```
self.textLabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Test File:" , font=NORM_FONT)
self.textLabel.pack()
```